# How to check how much number of indexes used by Outlook

Tags: windows, indexing, outlook

I'm using Outlook 2016 on Windows 7 and wondering how much number of indexes used by the Outlook. Please tell me how to check the number of indexes. In addition, while the indexes are being created, I would like to also konw how to check how much number of indexes created already.

Comment: I'd like to know how much total number of indexes used by Outlook and created already.

Comment: What indices? What exactly are you trying to do and why?

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's indices used to seach emails on Outlook 2016. I'd like to make sure progress of creating the indecies because it takes long time to create them. If there is any funcion of Windows API, please let me know.

Comment: You can use Windows search API for that, but keep in mind that it is really implementation specific - Exchange mailbox (even cached) can use Exchange search rather than local search.